# How to use this function that returns true in a if statment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like a very basic thing to do, but I don't understand why is not working: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy79ckn/)

```
function click(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
    return true;
  });
}

if(click()){alert('clicked')}
```

I want to return true if the button is clicked, is it possible to use the function directly into the if statement and then do something depending on the returned value ?

In the real scenario I need a function that can check for what button is clicked and depending on that I want to call other functions

```
if(click() == 'returned value'){differentFunction()}
```

Comment: You can't, at the point your doing the check the click has not yet happened..

Comment: The function you pass to `$('#button').click()` (and which you return from) is not the function you defined it inside (`function click()`)  which is what you are testing the return value of.

Comment: I don't think the answer that is shown as a duplicate is correct. This isn't an async call, it is about an event trigger. Similar, but different enough it shouldn't be marked a duplicate with that question. @Quentin

Comment: The function click will always return false. when the click handler is activated by you clicking the button the context of the function has been removed - the return true does not affect the if statement - which will have already happened on load anyway

Comment: Regarding your edit... This is logic you want to put inside the click handler, not surrounding the creation of the click handler.  "What button is clicked" could be accomplished by using different click handlers for different buttons, or by checking some value within the single common click handler (such as a data attribute on the buttons).

Comment: I was binding the click() method on multiple buttons `$('#btn1','#btn2')` and then checking for what id was clicked `if(this.id == 'btn1')(return value)`

Comment: @Uiot If you are binding to multiple buttons, and inside you are checking the id to determine which logic you need to do, meaning the logic for the buttons is not the same, then **don't bind to both buttons at the same time**.  Bind to them individually so you do not have to interrogate them, and just do whatever logic each one needs.

Comment: @samanime — The function passed to the click method is resolved *later* after the function which passes it there has resolved. That's what async is.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, but for someone who is asking this type of question, the one you linked won't make sense in the context of the question that is marked duplicate. To beginners, those two questions are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Your function `click()` sets a *handler*. It says, at a future time, when someone clicks `'#button'`, I want you to do a thing. Actually no "thing" has been set up because all the handler does is return. But it cannot return to your `if` because that will have long gone.

Perhaps put the `alert` inside the handler?

**`if` is not `when`.**

Comment: The **if is not when** made me understand, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confused over what the `click()` method does.

The `click()` method is a trigger, which when clicked will perform some action. It can't return a value like you want. All you need is this:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

If the button is clicked, that code will run. If it isn't clicked, it won't.

If you want it to only happen the first time it was clicked, you can use `once()`:

```
$('#button').once('click', function() { alert('clicked') });
```

which will only ever fire once.

Comment: Suggest emphasising "when" rather than "if" in your third prose line as that appears to be the source of some confusion.